# Test to analize answer to a survey

Tags: statistical-significance

I've a survey where 3 different group of people answer some question giving a score (from 1 to 5) to some statements. I have to find if there are significant differences between the answers of the three groups, what is the best statistical test to use for this purpose?

Comment: Three queries: ¿what is the sample size (total, and for each group)? ¿what are the anchors for the response scale? ¿what are the distributions of scores (e.g., normal, all 4s & 5s, etc.)?

Comment: There are two group of 15 people and one group of 22 people. The anchors where: 1- No difficulty , 2- little difficulty, 3-moderate difficulty, 4- A lot of diffculty, 5-Unable, the questions ask to say with what difficulty they are able to perform some actions.  The distribution of scores is not so predictable, in some question is decreasing, in other there are a lot of 1 and 5...

Comment: Your sample size is too small to do a chi-square test of independence. Your scale may (or may not) be interpretable as an interval measure.  If it is, then proceeding as indicated in the 1st answer posted is not unreasonable.  If not, then you may only be able to make a claim about different percentages at some given cut-point for the scale (eg, {1+2} vs. {3-5}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have ordinal variable in three groups, I'd consider Kruskal-Wallis test. It is a nonparametric alternative for ANOVA that can be used for ordinal data.

"Nonparametric" can be understand as "making no assumptions about distributions".

If it shows significant differences between groups, you can perform some nonparamatric post-hoc test like Dunn test. Or run pairwise comparisons with Mann-Whitney tests (nonparametric alternative for t-test) and apply some p-value correction (Bofferroni, Holm and many others).

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a two-sample individual t-test which would tell you how significant any differences in the average rating are.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test

Because you are using 3 groups, you need to compare every group with every other group to see if there are differences between any of them. For example, might turn out that group 2 has a statistically lower rating of 2.5 compared to group 3 with a rating 3.2.

In terms of sample size, since you are conducting this yourself, I don't imagine it is too big, so this test should suffice to show any differences.